# How to handle the zipfiles present in s3 that are actually returning size as -1 using ZipEntry?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip, zipinputstream

In my case, the zipfile is in S3 Bucket and we are trying to get the uncompressed size of it using ZipInputStream and its size as `entry.getSize()` which is actually returning -1.

I googled and found to use ZipFile,Enumeration and `zipfile.entries()` answer but how should I pass my s3 path of zip file to below.

```
ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("??????");
```

Any other way to get uncompressed size rightly? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is the combined size of all files in the zip is what you are expecting?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done without actually downloading the file. If possible, you could add a custom header in the file that denotes the uncompressed size.